# Get XML corresponding to node

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm developing an app that uses an XML (I'm using `javax.xml.parsers.Document` and friends) as input data.

When document misses something (misses in terms of my application logic) I'd show the user what is the wrong piece of XML, eg:

`input.xml`:

```
<root>
  <tag-a>
    <tag-b />
  </tag-a>
</root>
```

My application requires that `tag-b` cannot be used inside `tag-a` so I'd output:

```
Error: tag-b cannot have a tag-a as parent. Check:

input.xml:
   ...
   3: <tag-b />
   ...
```

XSD or DTD is not an option because my problem is more complex than this in the example.

In my code I deal with `Node`, `Element`, ... , what I need is a magical `getSourceXML` method, something like:

```
Element e = ...;
if (e /* something wrong */) { 
    System.err.println("Error " + e.getSourceXML());
}
```

Converting an `Element` in XML is not useful because there could be more than one similar element (eg: same tag-name/attributes) and I'd show the user the right one (eg. the one on line 7 instead of the one on line 45).

Comment: @vanje: I don't think it's an answer for my question because `XMLOutputter` writes the XML corresponding to an `Element`, what if there are more similar elements? I'd like to retrieve the original element, maybe with its code line.

Comment: I think the second answer is what you want.